# How can I deal with a heavy infestation of mealybugs on my potted Mandevillas?

Tags: plant-health, containers, tropical, mealybugs

I have several potted Mandevillas on my terrace, and I’ve been fighting a war on mealy bugs and black spot all summer. I’ve tried everything! Even replacing all plants at the same time and washing all planting materials (pots, etc.) with alcohol. Currently I’m using Neem Oil. These little suckers are so miserable that when you cut into any part of the plant, there is no sticky sap. All my plants have been sucked dry! I have never seen this before.

Note attached picture are leaves from from two separate plants. One leaf is in the beginning stages of black spot; and the other depicts a heavy mealy bug infestation on the back of the leaf.

Comment: You mention an attached picture - can you add that please?

Comment: Welcome Shem Kosches and thanks for the question! Are you having trouble posting pictures? Click on the icon next to the brackets and a window will open. Put in your picture or a link to it and enter.  If it doesn't work, leave a comment so we can help you! Our system is different from others, so check out our [tour] and have a look around our [help]. In addition to pictures, if there are any features or things about our site you need help with, just let us know!